# LanDesk, server patching trouble

Tags: windows-server-2008, landesk, patch-management

I've a server that contains lanDesk and i use it for patching other servers. But i've a trouble with a server (we name it r2d2), in lanDesk it says that the patch is succefull but on r2d2 it says that the patch is not installed.

How can i check it on r2d2 ?
A manual installation is preferable ?

Thank you

UPDATE :

A mate gave me a CMD command that returns all the updates on the server.

```
WMIC QFE > C:/patches.txt
```

But the patch isn't in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a manual installation and a reboot worked. The problem came from LanDesk. I'm still looking why LanDesk refused to patch the updates.